# Sort of repeated measure (that will be constant with one switch)

Tags: repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, independence

I cannot be specific about the data because it is proprietary.

However, suppose we have data for a large number of customers for about 150 consecutive days.  On each day, each customer can decide to renew or not.  Some people never renew, some people do.  Lets call that variable RENEW. So, renew has 150 values. Either 150 0's or 149 0's and a single 1.  There is also cumulative renew, which is similar but, once a person renews, it stays at 1.  So, each person could has 150 values again, any number of 0's and any number of 1s

I have been asked to model cumulative renew with logistic regression on a number of other variables about the client.

I pointed out that this violates independence of errors and said I thought we should measure ever renew, which would be a single value for each customer. But my client insists on the former. I also suggested survival analysis.

I don't think even a multilevel model will work here, since the repeat pattern is so strong.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems as though you have 150 y-variables (RENEW), each of which is binary, corresponding to each of 150 measurement times. If the interest is in whether or not a customer would ever renew (based on a set of features not described), it sounds like cumulative renew would be best.  Essentially you are just keeping a '1' if the customer renewed, irrespective of the date when it occurred, and '0' otherwise. I don't see an alternative, lest you create 150 separately models. Or perhaps you are interested in including date of renewal as a covariate?

Comment: Thanks, We definitely want date of renewal as a covariate. But your choices agree with mine.